# How to make HTTP request to a web server behind a Network Load Balancer (Layer 3)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, tcp, nlb, osi

I was just going through some Udemy AWS exam questions. There was a use case where a consumer vpc wants to connect to a service provider VPC via a vpc endpoint service. Therefore, we must use a Network load balancer (layer 3) instead of an Application load balancer (layer 7) in the service provider vpc - see picture.

As you can see, there is a Network Load Balancer with a web server behind. I'm wondering how a consumer can make a HTTP (layer 7) request to a web server that is sitting behind a layer 3 load balancer? Would that HTTP request not being dropped by the Network load balancer?

On the other hand, a TCP (layer 3) request would not provide you a website from a webserver, doesn't it?

Thanks!

[Link to Picture - AWS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2B0yv.png)

Answer (score 1):

HTTP (layer 7) works on top of TCP (layer 3). So there are no issues for HTTP requests going through NLB.

Comment: Wouldn't there be some information missing if you use TCP? 

If I compare this with an example of a layer 2 switch and a layer 3 router - A layer 2 switch cannot work with IP addresses, no? Even though IP works on top of MAC/

Comment: @Matt NLB does not have features of ALB, such as url path base routing.